Create or Delete subdomain programatically
To put in a different words, is there a way to add or delete DNS records programatically.
For example, If I am using GoDaddy, does GoDaddy provides any API kind of thing to update the DNS records.
Use case, If a New user signs up in my product, I wanted to create a subdomain and show a dashboard specific for that user

Found something related to godady - https://www.reddit.com/r/godaddy/comments/1bl0f5r/am_i_the_only_one_who_cant_use_the_api/

What you want might not be an API for this kind of thing, but a wildcard record (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), along with the correct TLS certificate, so you can simply handle any subdomain on your server. It's also faster because changes in the DNS might take time (because of caching and update frequency).
